# How to support German characters in Android 4.1 and up?

Tags: android

I am developing a simple application in which I have to display some German text; it's working fine in Android 2.3 to Android 4.0, but when I am testing on Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) it's not working anymore.

I have one WebView, I set data through `loadData` method. See the code below:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);
String chararc = "Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü";
mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
mWebView.loadData(chararc, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Here I attached screenshots of Android 2.3.1 and Android 4.1:
[image]

Comment: Its only happen in android 4.1 so I think its bug of jelly bean.

Comment: Try using the standard %xx hex encoding for characters outside the ASCII range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi, I got it.Here's the solution, I'm sure it will work.

```
   WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);

   String chararc = "Ä Ö Ü ä ö ü";

   mWebView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");

   mWebView.loadData(chararc, "text/html; charset=UTF-8",null);
```